# Flutter Flame - Performant Radar Mechanism

Tags: flutter, quadtree, flame

Assumed we would like to create a strategy game. What is the best way (using flutter together with the flame engine) to detect other units (e.g. enemies) around an element?

I've checked out the raycastall function https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.4.0/flame/collision_detection.html?highlight=ray#raycastall which somehow seems to do what I want but this also seems to be somehow inefficient. If one would for example create some kind of artillery with a huge radius, a couple of hundred rays may not be enough and a couple of thousand rays over a huge distance will most likely not be performant.

The other idea would be to just use a Circle ShapeHitBox https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.4.0/flame/collision_detection.html?highlight=ray#raycastall. As the game uses a QuadTree https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.4.0/flame/collision_detection.html?highlight=ray#quad-tree-broad-phase this should be performant.

Which one, in the context of a modern strategy game running a couple of thousand units, would be the better choice or are there any other mechanisms which would work out better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solid `CircleHitbox` should work if you need to know the components within the radius in every tick.

```dart
add(CircleHitbox(radius: <your radius>)..isSolid = true);
```

`isSolid` is needed since otherwise you'll only detect hitboxes the intersect the radius, and not the hitboxes that are fully within the radius.

Note that `isSolid` will be an argument in `v1.5.0` so that you don't need the cascade operator.

Comment: Isn't it already in 1.4.0?

Comment: The feature is in v1.4.0 but it is not an argument directly to the hitbox.